# JDBC error but no error when I run my query in MySQL workbench

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am running a query on a MySQL database, I am using JDBC and I am using MySQL workbench to run the query.

When I run it in MySQL work bench I get what I was expecting but when I run it in my code I get.

**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Character.CharacterID, Character.CharacterName, Characte' at line 1**

Here is the Java:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    try {
        result = s.executeQuery("USE `arbitrary-hero`; SELECT `Character`.CharacterID, `Character`.CharacterName, `Character`.CharacterLevel, SUM(ItemAttack), SUM(ItemHealth), SUM(ItemAgility), "
                + "SUM(ItemStrength), SUM(ItemSource) FROM `arbitrary-hero`.`Character` INNER JOIN `arbitrary-hero`.Character_Items ON `Character`.CharacterID = Character_Items.CharacterID INNER JOIN "
                + "Items ON Character_Items.ItemID = Items.ItemID WHERE Character_Items.Equiped = 1 and `Character`.CharacterName = "+ name[i] +" GROUP BY `Character`.CharacterName;;");
       }
       catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e);
       }
    }
    s.close();
```

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT `Character`.CharacterID, `Character`.CharacterName, `Character`.CharacterLevel, SUM(ItemAttack), SUM(ItemHealth), SUM(ItemAgility), SUM(ItemStrength), 
SUM(ItemSource) FROM `arbitrary-hero`.`Character` INNER JOIN `arbitrary-hero`.Character_Items ON
`Character`.CharacterID = Character_Items.CharacterID INNER JOIN Items ON 
Character_Items.ItemID= Items.ItemID WHERE Character_Items.Equiped = 1 and `Character`.CharacterName = "Maxinfet" GROUP BY `Character`.CharacterName;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, but I think you can't use two SQL commands together, so everything after the semi-colon is an error.

Comment: Dor has it right.  One SQL statement per `executeQuery` method invocation, please.  By the way, you should probably choose the mySQL database (the one mentioned in your `USE` statement) via your connection string instead.

Comment: Thank you, only having one SQL statement fixed the problem.